# How do I grep for a string in a file and display the previous 10 lines as well?

Tags: grep

I have a bunch of files, and I'm trying to find the ones that contain the string "EXECUTION FAILED" and also display the previous 10 lines prior to the "EXECUTION FAILED". I am wondering how I can do this?

Comment: All Unix tools have man pages - `man grep` will tell you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With :

```
grep -B10 'EXECUTION FAILED' files*
```

From

```
LESS=+/'^ +-B' man grep
```

> **-B NUM, --before-context=NUM**
> Print NUM lines  of  leading  context  before  matching  lines.
> Places  a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)  between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o  or  --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.